# Android emulator extended controls not updating emulator

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I've been playing with some of the extended controls for the Android Studio Emulator and noticed the emulator doesn't seem to update.  This is running stand alone and not in the tool window, so the extended controls shouldn't have problems.
Some things, such as Cellular: Data Status/Network Status, update fine, but other things like any of the battery settings don't.

If I toggle the screen with the power button then the emulator updates...sometimes.

How is it supposed to behave?  I don't see an update emulator button so I assume it's just supposed to read the settings and update the device.  It isn't critical to anything I'm working on, I'm just curious why it doesn't seem to be working right.